# No web application project after GWT is installed on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos, gwt

Here is a list of my installed software:

```
  Eclipse Standard/SDK  2.0.2.20140224-0000 epp.package.standard    null
  Google App Engine Java SDK 1.9.15 1.9.15  com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.feature.feature.group    Google, Inc.
  Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3 3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r43 com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e43.feature.feature.group  Google, Inc.
  Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.6.0  2.6.0   com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.feature.feature.group  Google, Inc.
  GWT Designer Core 3.1.3.r43x201405021502  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.feature.feature.group    Google, Inc.
  GWT Designer Editor   3.1.3.r43x201405021509  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.editor.feature.feature.group    Google, Inc.
  GWT Designer GPE  3.1.3.r43x201405021554  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gpe.feature.feature.group   Google, Inc.
  Tracer for OpenGL ES  23.0.4.1468518  com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.feature.group    The Android Open Source Project
  WindowBuilder Core    1.7.0.r43x201405021445  org.eclipse.wb.core.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  WindowBuilder CSS Support 1.7.0.r43x201405021453  org.eclipse.wb.css.feature.feature.group    Eclipse.org
  WindowBuilder XML Core (requires Eclipse WTP/WST) 1.7.0.r43x201405021458  org.eclipse.wb.core.xml.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org
```

I don't have the option for creating web app project however..my eclipse version is

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: Install the full version of the GWT Designer from the update site here:
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED by uninstalling CDT and everything related to Android development, and then reinstall GWT related

Comment: It works with ADT as I have used them in the past without issues. Perhaps CDT was the issue or your list of project types was just too long.

Comment: @Splaktar yea exactly..I uninstalled CDT and everything about Android (not sure about Android but I am pretty sure CDT is a part of the problem). Now GWT works like a charm on my Mountain Lion!